# Calculate $\lim_{z\to0} \frac{z}{|z|}$ , if it exists.

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Calculate 
$$\lim_{z\to0} \frac{z}{|z|},$$  if it exists.

Are sequences $(z_{n} )= \dfrac{1}{n} , (w_{n}) = \dfrac{i}{n}$ good counterexamples?

Comment: Your title says $z \to 1$ but question says $z \to 0$. Which is correct?

Comment: @AnuragA I have edited question, wrote $\to 1$ by accident

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, those sequences work. Or you can just note that $\frac{\lvert z\rvert}z=1$ if $z$ is a real number greater than $0$ and it is equal to $-1$ when $z$ is a real number smaller than $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{z}{|z|} = \frac{x+iy}{\sqrt {x^2+y^2}}$$

Let $y=0$ and we get $$\frac {z}{|z|} = \frac {x}{|x|}$$

Since $\lim_{x\to 0}  \frac {x}{|x|}$ does not exist the $\lim_{z\to 0}  \frac {z}{|z|}$

does not exist.